# Create deployments with kubectl version 1.18 +

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

At page 67 of [Kubernetes: Up and Running, 2nd Edition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kubernetes-up-and/9781492046523/), the author uses the command below in order to create a `Deployment`:

```sh
kubectl run alpaca-prod \
--image=gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue \
--replicas=2 \
--labels="ver=1,app=alpaca,env=prod"
```

However this command is deprecated with kubectl 1.19+, and it now creates a pod:

```sh
$ kubectl run alpaca-prod \     
--image=gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue \
--replicas=2 \
--labels="ver=1,app=alpaca,env=prod"
Flag --replicas has been deprecated, has no effect and will be removed in the future.
pod/alpaca-prod created

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.0", GitCommit:"e19964183377d0ec2052d1f1fa930c4d7575bd50", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-08-26T14:30:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.2", GitCommit:"faecb196815e248d3ecfb03c680a4507229c2a56", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-21T01:11:42Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Is there a way to use `kubectl run` to create a deployment with replicas and custom label with `kubectl` 1.19+?

Comment: I would suggest you to use `kubectl apply` with yaml resources. There you can define a deployment and later update it. And because this is how you would end up doing it on actual job.

Comment: `kubectl create deployment alpaca-prod --image=gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue --replicas=2` should do. But you'll need to add label after creation.

Comment: ...and check the YAML file into source control, so you have a record of what you deployed and you can recreate it later (possibly in a different environment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is now preferred to use `kubectl create` to create a new `Deployment`, instead of `kubectl run`.

This is the corresponsing command to your `kubectl run`

```
kubectl create deployment alpaca-prod --image=gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue --replicas=2
```

#### Labels

By default from `kubectl create deployment alpaca-proc` you will get the label `app=alpaca`.

The get the other labels, you need to add them later. Use `kubectl label` to add labels to the `Deployment`, e.g.

```
kubectl label deployment alpaca-prod ver=1
```

**Note:** this only adds the label to the `Deployment` and **not** to the Pod-template, e.g. the Pods will not get the label. To also add the label to the pods, you need to edit the `template:` part of the Deployment-yaml.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** With `kubectl version 1.18` things have changed. Like its no longer possible to use `kubectl` run to create `Jobs`, `CronJobs` or `Deployments`, only `Pods` still work.

So yes you cannot create a deployment from `kubectl run` from 1.18.

**Step 1:** Create `deployment` from `kubectl create` command

```
kubectl create deploy alpaca-prod --image=gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue --replicas=2
```

**Step 2** Update labels with `kubectl label` command

```
kubectl label deploy -l app=alpaca-prod ver=1

kubectl label deploy -l app=alpaca-prod app=alpaca

kubectl label deploy -l app=alpaca-prod env=prod
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the  `yaml` file which produces the expected result for p67 of 'Kubernetes: Up and Running, 2nd Edition':

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: alpaca-prod
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      ver: "1"
      app: "alpaca"
      env: "prod"
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        ver: "1"
        app: "alpaca"
        env: "prod"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kuard
        image: gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:blue
```